# Why doesn't plt.fill cover up the lines I've plotted before & How can I have the previous plots remain in all the images without copies of same code?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to have my code run through a few iterations where the everything in the plot except a 30 degree angle view is blocked out. So in this code I have 2 bugs: the fill won't cover up the line (blue and black) in the plot & the previous plots and graphs of the blue lines don't show up in all the outputed images of the code.

[The output of my code looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSnpB.png)

Below is my code:

```
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

# number of interior walls 
intwallnum = 3 

# room 
x= np.linspace(1, 22, 100)
y = np.linspace(1, 20, 100)

#plt.plot(x, y, 'w')

#interior walls case 1 
x1 = 8
x2 = 13  

y1 = 5
y2 = 10
y3 = 18

numpoints = 50 

w1 = np.linspace(x1, x2, numpoints)

xlist = [x1, x2]
ylist = [y1, y2, y3]

y1list = np.zeros(numpoints)
y2list = np.zeros(numpoints)
y3list = np.zeros(numpoints)

for i in np.arange(numpoints):
  y1list[i] = y1
  y2list[i] = y2
  y3list[i] = y3

plt.plot(w1, y1list, 'k', linewidth = 3)
plt.plot(w1, y2list, 'k', linewidth = 3)
plt.plot(w1, y3list, 'k', linewidth = 3)

#lines of view
cam1 = [0, 20]
cam2 = [22, 0]

# adjusted to apply with this prob specifically 
def eq(xpoint, ypoint, cam):
  m = (cam[1] - ypoint)/(cam[0] - xpoint)
  b = cam[1] - m*cam[0] 
  y = m*np.linspace(0,22,22) + b 
  return y

def eq2(xpoint, ypoint, cam):
  m = (cam[1] - ypoint)/(cam[0] - xpoint)
  b = cam[1] - m*cam[0] 
  y = m*np.linspace(0,22,22) + b 
  return [m, b]

fill_listx = []
fill_listy = []

fill_listx1 = []
fill_listy1 = []

#https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-elements-larger-than-a-specific-value-from-a-list-in-python/
for a in np.arange(len(xlist)*len(ylist)):   
  for j in np.arange(len(ylist)):
    for i in np.arange(len(xlist)):
      
      #plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 22, 22), eq(xlist[i], ylist[j], cam1), 'r', linewidth=1.)
      plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 22, 22), eq(xlist[i], ylist[j], cam2), 'b', linewidth=1.)
     
      if eq2(xlist[i], ylist[j], cam2)[1] >= 20:
        ptx = (20 - eq2(xlist[i], ylist[j], cam2)[1])/(eq2(xlist[i], ylist[j], cam2)[0])
      else:
        ptx = 0
      if eq2(xlist[i], ylist[j], cam2)[1] >= 20:
        pty = 20 
      else:
        pty = eq2(xlist[i], ylist[j], cam2)[1]     
      fill_listx = np.append(fill_listx, ptx)
      fill_listy = np.append(fill_listy, pty)

#camera 1 
      if eq2(xlist[i], ylist[j], cam1)[0]*(22)+eq2(xlist[i], ylist[j], cam1)[1] < 0:
        ptx = ( - eq2(xlist[i], ylist[j], cam1)[1])/(eq2(xlist[i], ylist[j], cam1)[0])
      else:
        ptx = 22
      if eq2(xlist[i], ylist[j], cam1)[0]*(22)+eq2(xlist[i], ylist[j], cam1)[1] >= 0:
        pty = (eq2(xlist[i], ylist[j], cam1)[0]*22+eq2(xlist[i], ylist[j], cam1)[1])
      else:
        pty = 0 
      fill_listx1 = np.append(fill_listx1, ptx)
      fill_listy1 = np.append(fill_listy1, pty)

for i in np.arange(intwallnum):
  y = ylist[i]
  
  if fill_listy[2*i+1] == fill_listx[2*i] or fill_listx[2*i] == fill_listx[2*i+1]: 
    filly = [fill_listy[2*i], fill_listy[2*i+1], ylist[i], ylist[i]] 
    fillx = [fill_listx[2*i], fill_listx[2*i+1], xlist[1], xlist[0]]
  else: 
    filly = [fill_listy[2*i],20, fill_listy[2*i+1], ylist[i], ylist[i]] 
    fillx = [fill_listx[2*i],0, fill_listx[2*i+1], xlist[1], xlist[0]]
  plt.fill(fillx, filly, facecolor='w',  alpha=1)

#camera 1   
for i in np.arange(intwallnum):
  y = ylist[i]

  if fill_listy1[2*i+1] == fill_listx1[2*i] or fill_listx1[2*i] == fill_listx1[2*i+1]: 
    filly1 = [fill_listy1[2*i], fill_listy1[2*i+1], ylist[i], ylist[i]] 
    fillx1 = [fill_listx1[2*i], fill_listx1[2*i+1], xlist[1], xlist[0]]
  else: 
    filly1 = [fill_listy1[2*i],0, fill_listy1[2*i+1], ylist[i], ylist[i]] 
    fillx1 = [fill_listx1[2*i],22, fill_listx1[2*i+1], xlist[1], xlist[0]]
  
  plt.fill(fillx1, filly1, facecolor='g', alpha=.75)

theta_deg = 15 
for i in np.arange(1, 90/theta_deg):
  angle = i*theta_deg
  x30 = np.linspace(0, 22, 22)
  y30 = -np.tan(angle*np.pi/180)*x30 + np.tan(angle*np.pi/180)*22

  y2 = -np.tan((angle+30)*np.pi/180)*x30 + np.tan((angle+30)*np.pi/180)*22


  if np.tan(angle*np.pi/180)*22 > 20: #y-intercept
    fillx = [22, 0, 0, (20 - np.tan(angle*np.pi/180)*22)/-np.tan(angle*np.pi/180)]
    filly = [0, 0, 22, 20]
    plt.fill(fillx, filly, facecolor='y', alpha=1)
    plt.plot(x30, y30, 'g','--')
  else: # Too lazy to code exception: line intesects (0, 20)
    fillx = [0, 22, 22, 0]
    filly = [20, 20, 0, np.tan(angle*np.pi/180)*22]
    plt.fill(fillx, filly, facecolor='y', alpha=1)
    plt.plot(x30, y30, 'g','--')

  #ax.set_facecolor("k")

  plt.xlim(0,22)  
  plt.ylim(0,20)
  plt.figure(figsize=(20, 22))

  plt.show()`


''''
```

Comment: To "cover up" previously drawn elements, you need to work with the `z` order (`zorder=...`).  By default, the z order for lines is `2`, and for filled areas it is `1`. So, `plt.fill(..., zorder=3)` would cover up everything with z order 1 or 2.